# prevent a propery from being serialized using a datacontractjsonserializer C#

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractjsonserializer

I am using the .net datacontractjsonserializer  to serialize my list of objects to a JSON string, but there are certain public properties that I don't want to serialize, how to prevent the datacontractjsonserializer  from serializing these properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two approaches when it comes to serializing with the .NET serializers:

**White-listing of properties:**

This is the recommenden approach. You mark your class explicitly with the `DataContract` attribute. With this, only properties that are marked with the `DataMember` attribute will be included in the output.

Instead of doing a black list of properties that you don't want to serialize, it's better to do a white list and mark all properties you DO want to be serialized. This is more safe, because it requires the developer to explicitly state that they want a property to be serialized when introducing a new property.

**Black-listing of properties:**

If you really want to do black listing, you can use the `IgnoreDataMember` attribute as pointed out by others. In this case you don't need to (and shouldn't) mark your class with the `DataContract` attribute. Instead you mark the properties you want to have excluded with `IgnoreDataMember`.

I hope this helps a bit to explain the choices and their advantages/disadvantages.

**Edit:** Expanded my answer

Answer (score 2):

There are two options, I can think of.

1- On the property try using [IgnoreDataMember] attribute.

2 - Do not mark your property with [DataMember] attribute.

Hope it helps